# how to set default value in dropdownlist and maintain the newly selected value after page refreshment

Tags: php

Hi I am doing a shopping cart in ajax. So far, I have added the products to my cart. The problem is in displaying the products in one's cart. I am trying to display the details of products in the form of a table.The problem is that I have to display the Quantity as a drop down list and initially I have to show the Quantity as the one user has selected while adding to cart. While viewing his cart he can change the quantity.When he changes the quantity the control goes to javascript and calculates the price there itself and passes the value to the php. My problem is that, when he changes the quantity,newly changed quantity is not shown in the dropdownlist. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When the javascript returns the price, it must be changing the value of some HTML element for display. Can you please check if its somehow affecting the value of the drop-down as well? Or it will be great if you can share some code snippet here.